# Manage Image Size

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, laravel

I'm facing a big problem right with saving bandwidth or storage now.

I have a website (PHP/Laravel), and it has 5-6 different image sizes in the desktop view. When a user uploads an image, I need to save 7 versions of that image, one being the main image and the other 6 being resized copies for various purposes.

And images need to be resized to fit the smaller screens of mobile devices, but it still desktop size (dimensions). To handle this, I need to use the `<picture></picture>` tag with multiple image sources, it means I need to create 3-4 resized copies for each image to ensure it matches all device screen sizes.

So, when a user uploads one image, I need to save at least 10 different image versions.

I have a method to convert all images to the WebP format, which can partially reduce the storage burden on my hosting. However, saving 11 different variants for a single image sounds like bad idea. Please help me find a solution to this issue.

find saving image better method

Comment: Browsers are able to scale images to the size needed in a page. So you don't need all possible sizes. Most of the time 3 sizes are enough: A small, normal and large size. Since the original is either small, normal or large itself, it can serve as one of the 3 image sizes, unless a format conversion is needed. Never generate images with larger dimensions than the original.

Comment: If you have a correctly written responsive design in your front end, the images should scale automatically, no matter what the original size was. To save bandwidth a bit you can scale down larger images and store a handful of versions as KIKO says, and then server the smaller ones in places in your page where you know it won't ever be displayed over a large area. So I agree, I don't think you need to store so many different copies of the image.

Comment: I apologize for providing limited information, but my main goal is to minimize the amount of data that needs to be loaded when accessing the website.

Comment: Two or 3 sizes ought to be enough then. Most websites find that sufficient. You have to compromise between that and using too much storage and adding too much complexity and processing in creating all the different sizes. Also you can't possibly be sure you will always match every single device and screen size - new devices and screens are released all the time, and people resize their browser windows etc frequently too. So that's not a realistic goal. At the very least a smaller image for mobile devices would be sensible, but don't go crazy.

Comment: Ok clear, thanks ADyson

Answer (score 0):

If you have a correctly written responsive design in your front end, the images should scale automatically, no matter what the original size was. So there shouldn't be a visual issue, even with larger image files.

Two or 3 sizes of the same image ought to be enough to cover your needs, unless your situation is very unusual. Most websites find that sufficient. You have to compromise between having lots of sizes (which might be slighly more efficient in terms of bandwith - although remember browsers can cache images) and using too much storage and adding too much complexity and processing in creating all the different sizes.

Also you can't possibly be sure you will always match every single device and screen size - new devices and screens are released all the time, and people resize their browser windows etc frequently too. So that's not a realistic goal. At the very least having a smaller version of the image for mobile devices / small screens would be sensible, but don't go crazy.